# Put $_POST data into an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I try to put all data from `$_POST` into an Array like this:

```
$produk =
        [
            'kode'=>$_POST['kode'],
            'id_kategori'=>$_POST['kategori'],
            'produk'=>$_POST['produk'],
            'keterangan'=>$_POST['keterangan'],
            'harga'=>$_POST['harga'],
            'potongan'=>$_POST['potongan'],
            'jumlah'=>$_POST['jumlah'],
            'berat'=>$_POST['berat'],
            'warna'=>$_POST['warna'],
            'ukuran'=>$_POST['ukuran']
        ];
```

but i always got an Error when i try to insert it into some Class and got this kind of error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function tambahProduk() on array in C:\wamp64\www\core\test.php on line 35
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function tambahProduk() on array in C:\wamp64\www\core\test.php on line 35
```

it work fine when i test my data using this:

```
$data =
        [
            'kode' => 'abcde',
            'id_kategori' => '1',
            'produk' => 'Topi',
            'keterangan' => 'Baju ini dibuat dengan penuh hati.',
            'harga' => '250000',
            'potongan' => '0',
            'jumlah' => '3',
            'berat' => '100',
            'warna' => 'merah, kuning, hijau',
            'ukuran' => 's, m, xl, xxl'
        ];
```

When i using `Print_r` on `$produk` i got this Result:

```
Array ( [kode] => JKW001 [id_kategori] => 1 [produk] => Baju Jokowi 01 [keterangan] => Kaos oblong enak sekali dipakai [harga] => 10000 [potongan] => 2 [jumlah] => 12 [berat] => 11 [warna] => merah, kuning, hijau, biru, coklat [ukuran] => A,B,C,D,E,F,G )
```

here what inside tambahProduct function:

```
public function tambahProduk($produk){
        try{
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO produk 
            (kode_produk, id_kategori, nama_produk, keterangan, harga, potongan, jumlah_tersedia, berat)
            VALUES (:kode_produk, :id_kategori, :nama_produk, :keterangan, :harga, :potongan, :jumlah_tersedia,
          :berat)';

            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':kode_produk', $produk['kode'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_kategori', $produk['id_kategori'], \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nama_produk', $produk['produk'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':keterangan', $produk['keterangan'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':harga',$produk['harga'] ,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':potongan', $produk['potongan'],\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':jumlah_tersedia',$produk['jumlah'] ,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':berat',$produk['berat'] ,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $id_produk = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

            $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO ukuran (ukuran) VALUE (:ukuran)';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql2);
            $ukuran = explode(",",$produk['ukuran']);
            $id_ukuran = [];
            foreach ( $ukuran as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':ukuran', $value);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $id_ukuran[] = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
                    //echo $value;
                    //print_r($id_ukuran);
                }
            }

            $sql3 = 'INSERT INTO ukuran_produk (id_produk, id_ukuran) VALUES (:id_produk,:id_ukuran)';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql3);
            foreach ( $id_ukuran as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id_produk', $id_produk);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id_ukuran', $value);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            }

            $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO warna (warna) VALUE (:warna)';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql4);
            $warna = explode(",",$produk['warna']);
            $id_warna = [];
            foreach ( $warna as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':warna', $value);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $id_warna[] = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
                    //echo $value;
                    //print_r($id_warna);
                }
            }

            $sql5 = 'INSERT INTO warna_produk (id_produk, id_warna) VALUES (:id_produk,:id_warna)';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql5);
            foreach ( $id_warna as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id_produk', $id_produk);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id_warna', $value);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            }

            $this->pdo->commit();
        }catch (\PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }

    }
```

so what can causing those error although the data is a same. Thanks.

Comment: The error shows that there is a problem calling the function `tambahProduk()`. How is this defined? And how do you want to call it?

Comment: As stated above, the issue is with your method `tambahProduk()`. You need to show us the code for the class in which the `tambahProduk()` is part off.

Comment: @akrys, Kitson, if the problem is in may tambahProduk() then it suppose i have problem when calling tambahProduk($data), but it's not. I only have problem when i'm calling using tambahProduk($produk). don't you think the problem is in $produk?

Comment: @Henra We don't know how `tambahProduk()` is defined and we don't know how you call this function. Perhaps `$produk` is an object and you all `$produk->tambahProduk()`. Then your object is overwritten by the array data array. We don't know as we don't know, what the code looks like. This is just a guess.

Comment: @akrys i edit the function and add what inside tambahProduct() is.

Comment: i mean i edit the question

Comment: @Henra And how is this function called? As there is `public` as a keyword, I guess it's inside a class. So it should be something like `$obj->tambahProduct($data)` or `$obj->tambahProduct($produk)`, right?

Comment: @akrys You should write an answer, since your assumption is the right one, as confirmed by the OP's comment under Soniya Reddy's answer. He says he calls `$produk->tambahProduk($produk);`, so this is pretty obviously the cause of the error, like the message precisely states: "Call to a member function on array". When affecting the POST data to `$produk` (which becomes an array), it overwrites the `$produk` object. Must merely choose another name for the array!

Comment: @akrys like cFreed said i calling it using $produk->tambahProduk($produk); it give me an error. but when i'm using $produk->tambahProduk($data); the function just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may be to do with `$_POST` for your `INT` values being passed as a string. So when your binding `$_POST` data to PDO as an `INT` it's failing.

An example of this below:

```
$_POST['test'] = '0';

if (filter_var($_POST['test'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {

    echo 'True';

} else {

    echo 'False';

}
```

Output:

```
False
```

I'd recommend that you cast your `$_POST` values to an `INT` using ternary like below:

```
$_POST['potongan'] = '0';

$pontogan = (is_numeric($_POST['potongan']) ? (int)$_POST['potongan'] : NULL);
```

So if `$_POST['potongan']` is numeric then cast `$_POST['potongan']` as `INT` and assign to `$pontogan` else `$pontogan` will be assigned `NULL`.

Comment: i think it's not about wrong input format, well i have validation class to validate the data so it won't input the incorrect one. I think the problem is in the array format in $produk.

Comment: Validation Class?? No mention of this in your question. I would advise adding this to your question. It maybe worth outputting your POST values as well by using 'var_dump($_POST)'

Answer (score 0):

Finally, let's summarize our discussion in the comments giving other people a chance to get a quick overview of what happened here:

The error `Call to a member function tambahProduk() on array` is not caused by the data format: `$data` and `$produk` are defined in the same way.

So, the function call is the problem: From the function definition, it became obvious that the function is defined inside a class. It turned out that the instance of this class was saved to `$produk`. The testing call with `$data` works so far: `$produk->tambahProduk($data);`

The call with the real data from `$_POST` doesn't work anymore. From the initial question it can be seen, that this data is also stored in `$produk`. So the function call would be: `$produk->tambahProduk($produk);`

And here we found the problem: In `$produk`, the data array from `$_POST` is stored. So there isn't any object anymore. That also means that the desired object's member function `tambahProduk()` can't be called anymore.

And what about the error message?

It says, there was a function call on array. That's because the data array was found inside of `$produk`. It should have been an object which has a function `tambahProduk()`.